# Algorithms with polynomial time complexity of higher order

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, asymptotics

I was learning about algorithms with polynomial time complexity. I found the following algorithms interesting.

- Linear Search - with time complexity $O(n)$
- Matrix Addition - with time complexity $O(n^2)$
- Matrix Multiplication - with time complexity  $O(n^3)$

Is there any algorithm with a higher complexity like $n^4$, $n^5$ etc? I would like to know about practical algorithms with polynomial time complexity only.

(I am familiar with algorithms having exponential complexity and class NP algorithms. My doubt is not about them.)

Comment: Practical with higher order! I don't think so. But there are polytime algorithms with a 1000 or 2000 or even more in the exponent.

Comment: Have a look at [Polynomial-time algorithms with huge exponent/constant](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/polynomial-time-algorithms-with-huge-exponent-constant/) on CSTheory.

Comment: Is your question about practical *algorithms*, or algorithms for practical *problems*? The two are very different. Furthermore, to call the complexity of (dense) matrix addition $O(n^2)$ might be construed as something of a misnomer; any algorithm doing (dense) matrix addition should take time proportional to the number of elements, and the input size - the matrices - will need space in the same proportion... so the complexity could justifiably be called $O(n)$ (where the problem size is the number of elements in the matrix).

Comment: [You mean $\Theta$ or $\Omega$, right](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use)? Also, [define "practical"](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/galactic-algorithms/). (Do you want to learn about algorithms or *problems*? I ask because there is no such thing as an "NP algorithm".)

Comment: @Juho They all only state upper bounds, how disappointing.

Comment: As pointed out in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65412/worst-known-algorithm-in-terms-of-big-o-more-precisely-big-theta/65422#65422 to decide if a convex hull in $d$-dimensional space is simplicial requires at least $\Omega(n \log n + n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor - 1})$ time.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Oh, right. The curse of dimensionality should yield many such examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) runs in time $\tilde{O}(n^6) \subseteq O(n^7)$, $n$ the length of the input number (in binary). This is the best known bound; as far as I know, there is no proven lower bound.

Comment: On the other hand, there is no reason to use AKS. You should use one of the probabilistic tests instead, with a probability of failure smaller than hardware failure.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus True, but that is probably the case for any algorithm with runtime in $\omega(n^3)$ in practice, and in some settings for all algorithms with runtime in $\Omega(n)$.